# "Self captured by enclosure before all members were initialized" using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, alamofire, swifty-json

I have been stumped with this app development question for quite some time now, and after viewing countless guides, tutorials, and examples, I decided the best route would be to build my code myself, using various Alamofire/SwiftyJSON examples where appropriate.

I am trying to create an app that displays a table of game servers and their statuses (name, players online, etc). I have a php-based API script that is able to check this information and return it in JSON format - a single-nested dictionary with no sub dictionaries.

To read this data, I have created a Swift file based on the `UITableViewController`, which among other things calls this function:

```
private func loadServers() {
    let server1 = serverInfo(endpoint: "https://example.com/api/serverInfo.php?host=555.555.555.55&port=5555")
    servers += [server1]
}
```

Ultimately, this will add it to my servers array and ideally to the table. However, my trouble exists in the `serverInfo` file's initialization. I have setup the file to store the data I want, like so:

```
//MARK: Properties

var name: String?
var map: String?
var game: String?
var game_desc: String?
var players: Int?
var maxPlayers: Int?

//MARK: Types

struct PropertyKey {
    static let name = "name"
    static let map = "map"
    static let game = "game"
    static let game_desc = "game desc"
    static let players = "players"
    static let maxPlayers = "maxPlayers"
}
```

I ultimately initialize the `serverInfo` with the following code, using Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

```
init(endpoint:String) {
    Alamofire.request(endpoint)
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                // handle failure
                return
            }
            if let value = response.result.value {
                let info = JSON(value)
                self.name = info["name"].stringValue
                self.map = info["map"].stringValue
                self.game = info["game"].stringValue
                self.game_desc = info["description"].stringValue
                self.players = info["players"].int
                self.maxPlayers = info["maxplayers"].int
            }
    }
}
```

However, I am receiving an error that says `'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized`. I have a feeling this has to do with the fact that the initialization of my various fields takes place within an API request that can fail, but I'm not entirely sure the best way to go about doing this sort of task.

Thank you for the time in reading my issue!

Answer (score 0):

You need a call to `super.init()` *before* you make there call to `Alamofire` and capture `self` otherwise any inherited state cannot be known to be initialised.

**In this case** that is sufficient as all your `var`s have optional type and are implicitly initialised to `nil`. However if you had a `var` with a non-optional type it too would need to be initialised to some value, e.g. something like:

```
var myInt : Int = 0
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Xcode seems to want me to include the 'override' keyword, as well as some other errors. Should the `super.init()` be empty?

Comment: You have to call one of the `init` functions defined by your superclass, you have to determine which one.